# How to create a stored procedure to combine several condition results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is the table structure:

```
TABLE TestTable 
(
       [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
       [Quality] [tinyint] NULL,
       [UtcTimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL, 
       [Value] [varbinary](max) NULL
)
```

What I want to achieve is: for the specified time range (`from` - `to`) for `UtcTimeStamp`, first I will query all data located at the time range. Then, continue to query the data after the `to` time range following this rule:

- R0: The `Quality` has three values: 1, 2, 3
- R1: If the first data `Quality` after `to` is 3, then just combine this one query result with above range results.
- R2: If the first data `Quality` after `to` is 2, then continue to query next row(after this `UtcTimeStamp`) which `Quality` is 3. Finally, combine these two query results with above range results.
- R3: If the first data `Quality` after `to` is 1, the continue to query next rows(after this `UtcTimeStamp`) which `Quality` is 2 and 3. Finally, combine these three query results with above range results.

All above job contains in one stored procedure, and with performance as possible as can.

I am not very familiar with stored procedure syntax, and tried to store some intermediate variables and use the `IF` `ELSE` syntax to combine all the results, just failed to get the sentence valid.

---

#### UPDATED

Here is the demo content:

**For R1:**

The database like this

```
Id(fake) UtcTimeStamp(fake) Quality Value
1s-..    1                  1       0x...
1s-..    2                  2       0x...
1s-..    3                  2       0x...
1s-..    4                  3       0x...
1s-..    5                  3       0x...
1s-..    6                  2       0x...
```

If I hope to query time range from 1 - 4, then the results should be:

```
Id(fake) UtcTimeStamp(fake) Quality Value
1s-..    1                  1       0x...
1s-..    2                  2       0x...
1s-..    3                  2       0x...
1s-..    4                  3       0x...
1s-..    5                  3       0x...
```

**For R2:**

The database like this

```
Id(fake) UtcTimeStamp(fake) Quality Value
1s-..    1                  1       0x...
1s-..    2                  2       0x...
1s-..    3                  2       0x...
1s-..    4                  3       0x...
1s-..    5                  2       0x...
1s-..    6                  2       0x...
1s-..    7                  1       0x...
1s-..    8                  3       0x...
```

If I hope to query time range from 1 - 4, then the results should be:

```
Id(fake) UtcTimeStamp(fake) Quality Value
1s-..    1                  1       0x...
1s-..    2                  2       0x...
1s-..    3                  2       0x...
1s-..    4                  3       0x...
1s-..    5                  2       0x...
1s-..    8                  3       0x...
```

**For R3:**

The database like this

```
Id(fake) UtcTimeStamp(fake) Quality Value
1s-..    1                  1       0x...
1s-..    2                  2       0x...
1s-..    3                  2       0x...
1s-..    4                  3       0x...
1s-..    5                  1       0x...
1s-..    6                  2       0x...
1s-..    7                  1       0x...
1s-..    8                  3       0x...
```

If I hope to query time range from 1 - 4, then the results should be:

```
Id(fake) UtcTimeStamp(fake) Quality Value
1s-..    1                  1       0x...
1s-..    2                  2       0x...
1s-..    3                  2       0x...
1s-..    4                  3       0x...
1s-..    5                  1       0x...
1s-..    6                  2       0x...
1s-..    8                  3       0x...
```

The procedure should something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ProcedureName] @Id as uniqueidentifier, @StartTime as datetime2, @EndTime as datetime2 AS ...
```

Comment: In fact, you just want us to do your work? Right? What have you tried on your own so far? I'm not quite sure what result you expect. Provide some demo data with an expected result.

Comment: @Ionic Actually, I planned to paste my codes here, but since it never complies successfully, I didn't do it.  Any suggestion is helpful, for example give some hints what syntax can be used here.

Comment: I post my answer a bit earlier and just post the demo content. I try a procedure based on that I understand of your logic later on.

Comment: I've added the code in my answer. You can try it. Hopefully I get your question right.

Comment: @Ionic Thanks. BTW, I have updated the demo content for my requirements.

Comment: Ah ok. Well I just created my own demo data to get to the procedure running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is my solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ProcedureName] @Id as uniqueidentifier, @StartTime as datetime2, @EndTime as datetime2 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextRow TABLE 
    (
        [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
        [Quality] [tinyint] NULL,
        [UtcTimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL, 
        [Value] [varbinary](max) NULL
    )

    DECLARE @BoundRows TABLE 
    (
        [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
        [Quality] [tinyint] NULL,
        [UtcTimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL, 
        [Value] [varbinary](max) NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO @NextRow SELECT top 1 * from [JerryTest].[dbo].[TestTable]
        where Id = @Id
        AND UtcTimeStamp > @EndTime

    IF((SELECT TOP 1 Quality FROM @NextRow) = 3)
        begin
        INSERT INTO @BoundRows SELECT * FROM @NextRow
        end
    ELSE IF((SELECT TOP 1 Quality FROM @NextRow) = 2)
        begin
        INSERT INTO @BoundRows SELECT * FROM @NextRow
        INSERT INTo @BoundRows SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [JerryTest].[dbo].[TestTable] 
            WHERE Id = @Id 
            AND UtcTimeStamp > @EndTime
            AND Quality = 3
        end
    ELSE IF((SELECT TOP 1 Quality FROM @NextRow) = 1)
        begin
        INSERT INTO @BoundRows SELECT * FROM @NextRow
        INSERT INTO @BoundRows SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [JerryTest].[dbo].[TestTable]
            WHERE Id = @Id 
            AND UtcTimeStamp > @EndTime  
            AND Quality = 2
        INSERT INTO @BoundRows SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [JerryTest].[dbo].[TestTable] 
            WHERE Id = @Id 
            AND UtcTimeStamp > @EndTime
            AND Quality = 3
        end

    (SELECT * FROM [JerryTest].[dbo].[TestTable] 
        WHERE Id = @Id 
        AND UtcTimeStamp >= @StartTime 
        AND UtcTimeStamp <= @EndTime)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM @BoundRows
END
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. I just try to generate some demo data first:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE dbo.temp
(
       [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
       [Quality] [tinyint] NULL,
       [UtcTimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL, 
       [Value] [varbinary](max) NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.temp(id, quality,UtcTimeStamp, value)
SELECT NEWID() as id, NTILE(3) OVER(ORDER BY object_id) as quality, 
    DATEADD(day,-NTILE(3) OVER(ORDER BY object_id),GETUTCDATE()) as UtcTimeStamp, 
    HASHBYTES(N'SHA1',CONVERT(nvarchar(36),NEWID())) as value
FROM sys.all_objects
```

You can try this procedure to get everything:

```
-- Doing the stuff inside the proc
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.yourProcedure 
    @from datetime2, @to datetime2
AS BEGIN

    ;WITH cte AS(
        -- Prepare data base for the second part of the query
        SELECT t.id, t.Quality, t.UtcTimeStamp, t.Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by t.UtcTimeStamp) as rn
        FROM dbo.temp as t
        WHERE t.UtcTimeStamp > @to
    )
    -- Get all data based inside the range of @from and @to
    SELECT t.id, t.Quality, t.UtcTimeStamp, t.Value 
    FROM dbo.temp as t
    WHERE t.UtcTimeStamp BETWEEN @from AND @to
    UNION ALL -- You can use union all, as you the following records won't already be in the above result set
    -- Add all rows which are behind the @to date (prepared in the cte)
    SELECT t.id, t.Quality, t.UtcTimeStamp, t.Value 
    FROM cte as t
    WHERE (t.Quality = 3 AND t.rn = 1) -- The first row, if it's quality 3
        -- All rows until quality 3, if the first row is quality 2
        OR ((t.quality = 2 and t.rn = 1) AND (t.rn <= (SELECT TOP 1 rn FROM cte WHERE quality = 3 ORDER By rn)))
        -- All rows until quality 2 or 3, if the first row is quality 1
        OR ((t.quality = 1 and t.rn = 1) AND (t.rn <= (SELECT TOP 1 rn FROM cte WHERE quality IN(2,3) ORDER By rn)))

END
GO
```

Afterwards call the result:

```
DECLARE @from datetime2 = DATEADD(day,-3,GETUTCDATE()), @to datetime2 = DATEADD(day,-2,GETUTCDATE())
SELECT @from, @to, * FROM dbo.temp

EXEC dbo.yourProcedure @from = @from, @to = @to
GO
```

Don't forget to cleanup afterwards.

```
-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE dbo.temp
```